# Get data from Spring-mvc to jstl

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i have spring mvc example set up and a student with a name returned to student.jsp:

return new ModelAndView("student","c", student);

If the student.jsp does not contain jstl, then it works ok:

```html
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>


<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/HelloWebForm/student" id="FORM_ID_01">
 <table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
   <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><form:textarea path="name" placeholder="default Value" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

but if i try to use jstl in student.jsp, then it does not work:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>

<body>

 <c:out value="${student.name}" />

</body>
</html>
```

It does not give any error messages, it just does not write anything out. What am i missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action you can do this:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
modelAndView.addObject("student", student);
modelAndView.setViewName("path/to/your/view");
return modelAndView;
```

And your view code is correct. I think this will work.